# Get the length of an array within a Perl hash

Tags: perl

I have the following:

```
$data{host} -> [$i] -> {someotherstuff}
```

How can I get the length of the array where [$i] is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$length = scalar( @{ $data{host} } );
```

Comment: and they say Perl syntax is convoluted (says the guy who's been using Perl since v2.x)

Comment: I always just tell people that Perl is ahead of it's time :-)

Comment: No need for `scalar`. `$length = @{ $data{host} }` would've worked just as well.

Comment: @Zaid: true but I like using scalar because I think it's clearer. I'm a crazy perl programmer who worries about maintainability :-D

Comment: If assignment to a scalar variable doesn't imply scalar context strongly enough, I'm not sure who you're expecting to be maintaining your Perl code.

Comment: `sprintf '%03d',@{$data{host}}` for instance, will not work, because the context isn't necessarily scalar.  So, if you hate the longwindedness of `scalar` there is the alternative `sprintf '%03d',0+@{$data{host}}` ... use the `0+` "Venus" numification operator

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last index, you can use: `$#{ $data{host} }`

Obviously, the length of the array is last index + 1. Use this notation when it is harder to achieve scalar context, or when you specifically want length-1. For example:

`0..$#{$data{host}}   # returns a list of all indices of the array`

Sometime useful.

Answer (score 1):

Answer added on account of [msw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875834#comment-2921749):

```
use autobox::Core;
# ...
$data{host}->length;
```

This works the same as Cfreak's answer, except with much less convoluted syntax, at the cost of using a module.

I have the thesis that most legitimate complaints about Perl can be simply answered with *»It does not need to be this way!«* and satisfied with short synopsis from CPAN.